# How can I get a solution for this?

Tags: html

I have two radio buttons:
yes and 
no

When I select 'yes',it should ask "Enter your requirements" and When I select 'no', nothing should happen.
I have tried this:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="question" value="yes">YES
<input type="radio" name="question" value="no">NO
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit  onclick="getValue('question')">
</form> 
<script>
function getvalue(question) {
    for (var i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
        var button = question[i];
        if (button.checked) {
            return button;
        }
    }
print getValue(question)
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Solution you get when you have tried. what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am new to coding.So i don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value='Yes' /><label for="radio1">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value='No'/><label for="radio2">No</label>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () { 
    $("input[name='radio']").on("change", function () {

      if($("input[name='radio']:checked").val() == "Yes"){
        alert("Enter your requirements");
      }
    });

});
```

[JSFiddle try this](http://jsfiddle.net/prasanthar/opwyytra/)